# CSS color looks different depending of the screen

Tags: css

I have a div with a background color #74cfbf. On laptop it's blue and on computer it's green. Do you know why ? And how to fix it

On computer and mobile:

[image]

On laptop:

[image]

Comment: Different monitors can result in different rendered colors. I'm doubtful there's much you can do about it without direct access to the machine you'd want to tweak.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: what?like,what?

Comment: thanks but there is a huge difference, it's suppose to be a kind of green and on some computer it's blue.

Comment: @Ihor, it's a simple css div{background: #74cfbf;}

Comment: If you examine the div in your browser's Dev Tools on both devices, do they show the same hex code? If so, it could just boil down to the monitors you are using.

Comment: yes the hex code is correct on both screen

Comment: I have add screenshot of the result on computer and laptop

Comment: I went ahead and pulled open a color hex site for #74cfbf on both my laptop and PC, and they both look like the 2nd screenshot you added labeled "laptop". I believe it is just depends on the monitor settings and how light/saturated the screen is.

Comment: This results from hardware differences, not anything to do with programming. As such it's off-topic for this site.